# Converting output of dependency parsing to tree

Tags: python, data-structures, nlp, dependency-parsing

I am using `Stanford dependency parser` and the I get the following output of the sentence

> I shot an elephant in my sleep

```
python dep_parsing.py 
[((u'shot', u'VBD'), u'nsubj', (u'I', u'PRP')), ((u'shot', u'VBD'), u'dobj', (u'elephant', u'NN')), ((u'elephant', u'NN'), u'det', (u'an', u'DT')), ((u'shot', u'VBD'), u'nmod', (u'sleep', u'NN')), ((u'sleep', u'NN'), u'case', (u'in', u'IN')), ((u'sleep', u'NN'), u'nmod:poss', (u'my', u'PRP$'))]
```

**I want to convert this into a graph with nodes being each token and edges being the relation between them.**

I need the graph structure for further processing hence it would help if modification to it are easy and also must be easily representable.

Here is my code till now.

```
from nltk.parse.stanford import StanfordDependencyParser
stanford_parser_dir = 'stanford-parser/'
eng_model_path = stanford_parser_dir  + "stanford-parser-models/edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishRNN.ser.gz"
my_path_to_models_jar = stanford_parser_dir  + "stanford-parser-3.5.2-models.jar"
my_path_to_jar = stanford_parser_dir  + "stanford-parser.jar"

dependency_parser = StanfordDependencyParser(path_to_jar=my_path_to_jar, path_to_models_jar=my_path_to_models_jar)

result = dependency_parser.raw_parse('I shot an elephant in my sleep')
dep = result.next()
a = list(dep.triples())
print a
```

How can I make such a graph structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can traverse over `dep.triples()` and get your desired output.

**Code:**

```
for triple in dep.triples():
    print triple[1],"(",triple[0][0],", ",triple[2][0],")"
```

**Output:**

```
nsubj ( shot ,  I )
dobj ( shot ,  elephant )
det ( elephant ,  an )
nmod ( shot ,  sleep )
case ( sleep ,  in )
nmod:poss ( sleep ,  my )
```

For more information you can check : [NLTK Dependencygraph](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/parse/dependencygraph.html) methods `triples()`, `to_dot()` and `dep.tree().draw()`

Edit -

The output of `dep.to_dot()` is

```
digraph G{
edge [dir=forward]
node [shape=plaintext]

0 [label="0 (None)"]
0 -> 2 [label="root"]
1 [label="1 (I)"]
2 [label="2 (shot)"]
2 -> 4 [label="dobj"]
2 -> 7 [label="nmod"]
2 -> 1 [label="nsubj"]
3 [label="3 (an)"]
4 [label="4 (elephant)"]
4 -> 3 [label="det"]
5 [label="5 (in)"]
6 [label="6 (my)"]
7 [label="7 (sleep)"]
7 -> 5 [label="case"]
7 -> 6 [label="nmod:poss"]
}
```

Comment: `dep.tree().draw()` does create a tree, however, I want a directed graph with edges being the relation between two terms, which is missing in this case . How can I create/display this?

Comment: Then I think you want print dep.to_dot(), For layout : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_(graph_description_language)#Layout_programs

Comment: Yes it worked, but now how can I add something into that graph without modifying the existing triple (since it returns unicode)? also how can I view graphically (like some image popping up etc. not just in terminal) ? is there any library?

Comment: However, I will accept your answer since it partially solved my query.

Comment: DOT is standard format. For layout you can check - Graphviz and others on wikipedia page which I mentioned in previous comment.