# Dependency Parsing using Stanford Dependency Parser

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, stanford-nlp, dependency-parsing

i am trying to extract main verb in a sentence and i followed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19751230/how-can-we-extract-the-main-verb-from-a-sentence) , i am expecting output in this format

```
nsubj(swim-4, Parrots-1)
aux(swim-4, do-2)
neg(swim-4, not-3)
root(ROOT-0, swim-4)
```

but i am getting output in this way

```
[<DependencyGraph with 94 nodes>]
```

i did following

```
  dependencyParser = stanford.StanfordDependencyParser(model_path="edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz")
  print (list(dependencyParser.raw_parse(noiseLessInput)))
```

i think i am doing something wrong, how can i achieve desired ouput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah, found how to do that through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39340907/converting-output-of-dependency-parsing-to-tree), but it is not showing root attribute, that's the only issue now

```
  dependencyParser = stanford.StanfordDependencyParser(model_path="edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz")
result = dependencyParser.raw_parse(noiseLessInput)
dep = result.__next__()
for triple in dep.triples():
 print(triple[1], "(", triple[0][0], ", ", triple[2][0], ")")
```